# How to remove a html element from a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do temporary disable a html element from a html page:

```
<i class="fa fa-eye fa-2"></i> <span class="feat-info-text"></span>
```

Actually, i want to remove the mentioned all lines from a html page source through javascript/jquery code by place in `<head></head>` tag.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great questions tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: Why would you place it in the `head` tag?

Comment: Show us the surrounding HTML as well as it relates to the answer.

Comment: @Anthony He's talking about putting the JS in the `head`, not the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following and find the elements with the class attributes like so, but it is you may want to give your elements IDs so you can refer to them​more easily.

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-eye fa-2"></i>
<span class="feat-info-text"></span>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fa.fa-eye.fa-2, .feat-info-text").remove();
});
```

#### Note

You may want to hide the elements instead of removing them from the [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). I am not sure what your context is, but it is something you may want to consider.

Comment: Could you explain me why selector by classes are a bad practice? if you need to hide 100 spans, do you put 100 ids?

Comment: Oh, in that case you definitely should use classes. The question just seemed to imply that those were the only 2 elements to be removed, in which case there may be other elements with the same class, but there would only be one with that id. There&#39;s nothing **wrong** with using classes, it just is neater to use IDs if you only have just 1 or 2 different elements to remove

Comment: @quirimmo but you are probably right anyway. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thank you @Benzadon many many thanks for the better explanation.

Comment: @Baki glad I could help :)